# How can I get the inner type of a generic class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I know with Kotlin (on the JVM) I can get the type of a class with `foo::class`. And I know I can generic information, even at runtime, with `typeOf<>()` (as long as my function is inline). But I can't figure out how to get `Int` from a `List<Int>` for example.

Here's as far as I can get:

```
import kotlin.reflect.KType
import kotlin.reflect.typeOf

fun main() {
    TypeTest.get<Int>()
    TypeTest.get<List<Int>>()
    TypeTest.get<Map<String, List<Int>>>()
}

class TypeTest {
    companion object {
        @OptIn(ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)
        inline fun <reified OUT : Any> get() {
            generateReturnType(typeOf<OUT>())
        }

        fun generateReturnType(type: KType) {
            val classifier = type.classifier!!
            println("class $classifier has parameters ${classifier::class.typeParameters}")
        }
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
class class kotlin.Int has parameters [T]
class class kotlin.collections.List has parameters [T]
class class kotlin.collections.Map has parameters [T]
```

Given a KClassifier, how can I get its inner type (ideally recursively, in the case of a `List<List<Int>>`)? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: `println("class $type has parameters ${type.arguments}")`? https://pl.kotl.in/SSs51Iv9E

Comment: Thanks - that's exactly what I needed, I must have missed that in the documentation. Feel free to respond with an answer and I'll mark it.